# How do I gracefully load a specific localization file dynamically in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Currently, I have a system which has language codes such as `en, de, jp` and so on. I need to provide localisation for 8 languages, so it works if I manually add in the script file here:

`<script src='/js/locale/angular-locale_de.js'></script>`.

But I need to be able to load it dynamically in the header. I tried using a jQuery hack using `("head").append()` but on Chrome throws an error says ASYNC request deprecated.

Comment: Why do you need to do this dynamically? According to angular's documentation, you can just have all of them in the app at the same time and it should work.

Comment: How would that happen? I need to tell the app to load the appropriate script with the specific language code.

Comment: Sorry, I misread their doc. You are right that you can only have one loaded at once. This might interest you though: http://sbouchard.github.io/angular-dynamic-i18n/#!/usage

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/29348559/1257504

Comment: If you have different code for different languages, perhaps you should be using a dictionary that provides the translations by key/getter, and provide that as an Angular service?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to invent the wheel, there's a module -angular dynamic localization- for that and it's pretty straight forward:
https://github.com/lgalfaso/angular-dynamic-locale

and if you are looking for translation, there u go
http://angular-translate.github.io/

Answer (score 0):

You could use http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/ if you're already using jQuery.

Comment: Will that load it in the head, don't think so?