# Angularjs - To load a js file in html code fragment (snippet)

Tags: angularjs

I am working with AngularJs and i have a doubt.

This is my html code:

```
<header id="menu" ng-include="'pages/menu.html'"></header>
<main>
    <!-- Aquí inyectamos la vista -->
    <div ng-view></div>
</main>
```

I want to load a js file for the menu.html file, how could do it?

Have i to create a directive ng-controller in the header with id="menu"? or can i associate a js inside my menu.html file?.

I have a file js main with the routing app (main.js), but i would like to load a separate js file (menu.js) for menu.html file.

Thanks,

Comment: you can check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23656231/angularjs-dynamic-loading-of-external-js-based-on-routes

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can just include it in menu.html