# Applying external CSS in AngularJS 1

Tags: css, angularjs

Is it possible to apply an external CSS to a component in AngularJS1?
And if so - how?
I could find only examples which apply inline css...

Comment: see more about lazy-load here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29348559/3332734

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AngularJS component's template is nothing different then a regular HTML template. So including the CSS in one of the [standard ways](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp) should work.

Inside of the HTML of your template use:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">
```

Where `theme.css` will be replaced with the absolute path to your external CSS.