# load only controller files on demand while routing Angularjs and requirejs

Tags: angularjs

I know this question maybe duplicate.But I am still not getting valid results based on those answers.Anyways i have following doubt:
I want to implement angularjs with loading controller files on demand, with template routing.I have used requirejs concept for this.But I am not able to load ONLY controller files on demand.
For ex.

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        controller:'page1',//I want to load controller file here
        templateUrl:'page1.html'
    });
});
```

I have used **resolve** concept here,but it didn't helped.
In above code I want to load controller file and also bind it to respective view.Please provide any solution or reference.If possible please provide detailed solution.
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20909525/load-controller-dynamically-based-on-route-group

Comment: any comments here