# Difference between app.register.controller and app.controller in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I don't know when to use app.register.controller and app.controller to create controller after module is created. I have googled but I didn't find clear difference between two scenarios. please post sample example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Simple Answer

You can use `app.controller` to register providers before the app run (i.e., before bootstrap or `ng-app`, at config time). And `app.register.controller` is used to register a new provider when the app has already been bootstrapped (i.e., it's running).

#### A More Elaborated Explanation

AngularJs loads all providers that were registered before the module gets bootstrapped, once your module gets bootstrapped, angular won't look for registered providers anymore. It's fine for most apps, but, in some cases, you will have to load new providers at run time (i.e., after the app gets bootstrapped), that's called lazy loading. Therefore, provided that angular won't look for registered components anymore, you will have too register it manually.

For example:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myController1', function (){});

angular.element(documento).ready(function () {
    // equivalent to ng-app attribute
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
});
```

At this point, angularjs will load all providers registered before the bootstrap phase. However, if you try to register a controller again, it won't get loaded on your application, because angularjs loads it just when bootstrapping the app.

So, to register a provider at run time, you have to expose the angularjs' provider and component factories on your module like so:

```
app.config(function($controllerProvider, $compileProvider, $filterProvider, $provide) {
    app.register = {
        component: $compileProvider.component,
        controller: $controllerProvider.register,
        directive: $compileProvider.directive,
        filter: $filterProvider.register,
        factory: $provide.factory,
        service: $provide.service
    };
});
```

Check this answer for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20922872/4488121

Finally, now it allow you to register a provider after the app bootstrap (i.e., at run time).

```
app.register.controller('myController2', function (){});
```